# Mounting external HDD via windows/Virtualbox

Tags: 12.04, windows, virtualbox

I have a windows 7 laptop with a VM running Ubuntu 12.10.

I have an IDE HDD that I'd like to access, which is a USB HDD. I have plugged this into my windows machine, but it is not showing up as a drive.

What I'd therefore like to do, is mount this on my Ubuntu VM.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Windows have to see the drive, before you can access it in VM.

Comment: Ok. The problem is that the HDD has an old Ubuntu install on it. I'm guessing that is the reason why Windows doesn't recognise it.

Comment: How is the drive formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed VirtualBox with extensions, after plugging in your USB HDD, you should be able to open the machine settings, open the USB page, and add the HDD drive as a device accessible from the VM. Start the VM and it should see the USB HDD as if it were a USB drive.